# How to calculate the absolute value for an array in python?

Tags: python

How to calculate the absolute value for an array in python?

for example:
a = [5,-2,-6,5]

I want to know the max of abs(a), and the answer should be 6.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`max(abs(i) for i in [5, -2, -6, 5])`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import numpy
max(numpy.absolute(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
a = [5, -2, -6, 5]
print max(abs(x) for x in a)
```

The `max` function can accept an iterable, and `abs(x) for x in a` is a generator which will give the absolute value of each element in `a`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternately you could use:

```
max(map(abs, [5,-2,-6,5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max(abs(i) for i in [5, -2, -6, 5])
```

The List Comprehensive Solution :)