# How to find the highest magnitude int in a Python list?

Tags: python, max

If a list has positive and negative integers, how can I find the value of the item in the list that has the largest magnitude?

Comment: `max(map(abs, List))`

Comment: `max(values, key=abs)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to caculate the absolute value for an array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777737/how-to-caculate-the-absolute-value-for-an-array-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late reply, but the other answer and the linked duplicate question seems to have missed an important aspect of your question, namely that you want the *value*, not the *absolute value*, with the largest magnitude. In other words, in a list like `[-10, 0, 5]`, you want the result to be `-10`, not `10`.

To get the value with its original sign, you could (conceptually) follow these steps:

1. Get a copy of your list where all values were converted to their absolute values
2. Find the *index* of the value that has the maximum absolute value
3. Return the *value* at that index

This can be done quite easily in numpy by using `argmax`, which returns the index of the maximum value from an array. Step-by-step, it would look like this:

```
# Create a numpy array from the list you're searching:
xs = np.array([-10, 0, 5])

# Get an array where each value is converted to its absolute value:
xs_abs = np.abs(xs) 
# This gives [10, 0, 5]

# Get the index of the highest absolute value:
max_index = np.argmax(xs_abs) 
# This gives 0

# Get the number from the original array at the max index:
x = xs[max_index] 
# This gives -10
```

This can be done in a single line like so:

```
x = xs[np.argmax(np.abs(xs))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean highest magnitude regardless of negative or positive sign, then you would take the maximum of the list resulting from taking the absolute value of each constituent list value. Does that make sense?

```
Here is an example:
numbers = [3, 5, 7, -18]

matrix=[]
for x in numbers:
    matrix.append(abs(x))
max(matrix)
```

Comment: This could be done much more tersely by using a generator comprehension: `max(abs(n) for n in numbers)`. Or even better using the `key` keyword of `max`: `max(numbers, key=abs)`

Comment: That is probably the most inefficient way you could've solved this.

Answer (score 0):

this will find the largest value in the list and convert it to positive (afterwards). Useful for normalizations
abs(max(xs,key=abs))